# Jquery find doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  problem to get the content of the span (Arrière in this example), when its parent (li) contains a span with class 'checked'

This is my html

```
<fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
    <label class="attribute_label">Base du siège &nbsp;</label>
        <div class="attribute_list">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <span class="checked">
                            <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="26" checked="checked">           
                        </span>
                    </div>
                   <span>Arrière</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end attribute_list -->
</fieldset>
```

I tried this jquery code:

```
$('.attribute_fieldset').each(function( index ) {
    var attribute_label = $(this).children('.attribute_label').html();
    var attributeval = $(this).find('.checked').parent('.radio').next('span').html();
    console.log(attributeval);
    var that = this;    
  $('#product_attributes').append('<li>'+attribute_label.replace('&nbsp;','')+':');

});
```

I got undefined for attributeval

Comment: works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/19a6526w/)

Comment: maybe you didnt include the script since ^ works

Comment: Working fine [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQwgbG](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQwgbG)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amzrcco5/ its working. for the given html and css.

Comment: i would guess you don't have jquery before your script and there is a _$ is undefined_ error, right!

Comment: I have no errors, i get undefined in the console, this is the live link http://www.lebonsiege.fr/sieges-personnalisables/4644-mirra-2-dossier-butterfly.html#/28-accoudoirs-n/38-support_lombaire-n2/58-roulettes_patins-bb/25-base_du_siege-mrf131/49-finition_accoudoirs-63/54-finition_assise_airweave_2-1a705/43-finition_dossier_butterfly-zk_8m23/34-pietement_structure_listing-6ka/37-reglage_de_la_profondeur_d_assise-af

Comment: wow that was one hell of code...so heavy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('.attribute_fieldset').each(function() {
   $('#product_attributes').append('<li>' + $(this).find('attribute_label').html().replace(' &nbsp;', '') + ':' + $(this).find('li span.checked').parent().next('span').html() + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: with li span.checked selector, but in document load event, i got undefined variable, i think that the dom is not ready yet

Comment: @tarekfellah Then just put the code snippet inside: $(document).ready(function(){ ........... });

Comment: It's already inside a document ready, the page is too slow that the dom is not yet loaded, i have added a timeout to get it work

Comment: Take into account that the $(document).ready(function(){ ........... }); is specifically used for waiting JS code to start execution after all DOM elements are loaded. You do not need a timeout for this. If your page is very heavy and loading takes much time, you should consider wrapping all of your JS code inside the ready() declaration ;)

Comment: Ok, then you should consider using $( window ).load(function() { ... }) instead of ready(). See the documentation (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for more information ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead you can try below code:
$(".attribute_fieldset span").each(function(index, spanElement) {
    if($(spanElement).parent().find("span.checked").length
         && !$(spanElement).hasClass("checked")) {
        console.log(spanElement); // this is the span element you want
        console.log(spanElement.text()); // this is the value "Arrière"
      }
});
```

Comment: No! it would not get the targeted span.